# Recursive formula for recurrence that takes 2 arguments

Tags: recursion, asymptotic-complexity

I can create a recursive formula from recurrences where it only passes down one argument (something like $T(n/2)$). However, for a case like this where the value of $u$ and $v$ are different, how do I put them together? This is the problem:

The call to recursive function RecursiveFunction(n, n) for some n > 2

```
RecursiveFunction(a, b) 
if a >= 2 and b >= 2
   u=a/2
   v=b-1
   RecursiveFunction(u, v)
```

The end goal is to find the tight asymptotic bounds for the worst-case running time, but I just need a formula to start first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are in fact two different answers to this, depending on the relative sizes of `a` and `b`.

The function can be written as follows:

[image]

Where `C` is some constant work done per call (`if` statement, pushing `u, v` onto the call stack etc.). Since the two variables evolve *independently*, we can analyse their evolution separately.

1. `a` - consider the following function:

   [image]

   Expanding the iterative case by `m` times:

   [image]

   The stopping condition `a < 2` is such that:

   [image]
2. `b` - as before:

   [image]

The complexity of `T(a, b)` thus depends on which variable reaches its stopping condition first, i.e. the smallest between `m` and `n`:

[image]

Comment: actually a and b starts off having the same size because the general set up is RecursiveFunction(n, n) for some n > 2

Does it make any change to the result?

Comment: In that case it is `O(log n)`, because in the asymptotic case `log n` is always smaller than `n`